# Update query with nested subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data of different months. I want to update 'PUC_AVG_UCOST' with data from the same table where the date is max date
My sql is as follows

```
update  lty_prd_u_cost a
    set PUC_AVG_UCOST= 
        ( SELECT  PUC_AVG_UCOST
            from  lty_prd_u_cost b
            where  PUC_DATE=
                ( SELECT  max(c.PUC_DATE)
                    from  lty_prd_u_cost c
                    where  b.PUC_PRD_NAME=c.PUC_PRD_NAME
                ) 
        )
    where  a.PUC_AVG_UCOST=0
      and  puc_date='2021-08-31'
```

There is the following error

[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Kindly help me correct it

[image]

[image]

IF I can not find a value for the current month the value of the immediate past month will be taken as the current month Value.

Comment: Sounds like there are 2 rows on the last day.  Show some of the data so we can point that out.

Comment: Could you help me with a solution please

Comment: That's the data _before_ the `UPDATE`, correct?  What should the data look like _after_?

Comment: I have  give a SS before and after update

Comment: Since the names is "AVG", does that mean "average".  If so, why isn't the value (2300+0)/2 = 1150 ?

Comment: Pls ignore the Avg World. I want to update the Value in previous month record to current month record

Comment: Will the value be the same _every_ month?

Comment: IF  I can not find a value for the current month the value of immediate past month will be taken as current month Value.

Comment: That makes it more complex.  Please add an example of such in your data.

Answer (score 2):

This query doesn't work because the only circumstance in which a subquery will work in the SET statement is if it produces a single value (like, `(SELECT max(PUC_DATE))` would just be 2021-08-31). As it's written, the subquery produces a row for every PUC_PRD_NAME. And it's asking it to write ALL these rows in the subquery for EACH row in the UPDATE statement, which is impossible.

Try joining the subquery (which I've modified) to the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE lty_prd_u_cost a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT PUC_PRD_NAME, PUC_AVG_UCOST
    FROM (
        SELECT PUC_PRD_NAME, PUC_AVG_UCOST
            ,row_number() over (partition by PUC_PRD_NAME order by PUC_DATE desc) as rn
        FROM lty_prd_u_cost
        ) b0
    WHERE b0.rn = 1
) b
ON a.PUC_PRD_NAME = b.PUC_PRD_NAME
SET a.PUC_AVG_UCOST = b.PUC_AVG_UCOST
WHERE a.PUC_AVG_UCOST=0
    and a.PUC_DATE = '2021-08-31'
```

Comment: It gives the following error message                                                                                                                                        [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'PUC_PRD_NAME' in 'field list'

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ fixed it- I forgot to include `FROM lty_prd_u_cost` in the inner subquery.